# Cannot retrieve links from html table using selenium and python

Tags: python, css, parsing, selenium, hyperlink

I'm trying to retrieve the links from this html table using selenium, since the website uses JavaScript. The problem is, that while I can get the text values, I am still unable to select the links that will be used to continue the scrapping.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="Center" border="0" id="SearchResultsGrid" width="600">
<tr align="Center" valign="Middle">
<td align="Left"><font face="Verdana" size="1">id1</font></td><td><font face="Verdana" size="1"><a href="http.url.com" target="_self">"name1</a></font></td><td align="Center"><font face="Verdana" size="1">prop1</font></td>
<td align="Left"><font face="Verdana" size="1">id2</font></td><td><font face="Verdana" size="1"><a href="http.url2.com" target="_self">name2</a></font></td><td align="Center"><font face="Verdana" size="1">prop2</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My code is:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_id("SearchResultsGrid")
links = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

have also tried to use table.find_element_by_xpath() to no avail..

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for my question:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_id("SearchResultsGrid")
links = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
    driver.get(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

The key was using the `get_attribute("href")` method.